# PIR motion sensor

Tags: hardware, software-installation

I'm working on a magic mirror, and this is my first Pi project. I've got the mirror all set, and are trying to connect a pir sensor to it, so the display will only be on after the sensor has detected motion.

The problem i'm having is that the PIR is detecting motion even if there isen't any. What am I missing?

The code I'm using to detect motion:

```py
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as io
import subprocess

io.setmode(io.BCM)
pir_pin = 8
SHUTOFF_DELAY = 30

last_motion_time = time.time()
turned_off = False
io.setup(pir_pin, io.IN)

while True:
    if io.input(pir_pin):
            last_motion_time = time.time()
            print("POWER ON")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if turned_off:
                    turned_off = False
                    subprocess.call("sudo /home/pi/projects/python -p && fbset -accel true",shell=True)

    else:
            if not turned_off and time.time() > (last_motion_time + SHUTOFF_DELAY):
                turned_off = True
                subprocess.call("sudo fbset -accel false && /home/pi/projects/python -o",shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
```

The code is returning "POWER ON" at the rate of time.sleep(X).

[image: The PIR connection to the pi]

This is how i have wired it, have tried to change the signal to Pir_pin = 4. With no change. If i remove the signal cable from the pie, "POWER ON" stops printing, so I figure that the PIR is connected, and somthing is wrong with my code. But I can't figure out what..

I have also tried to change the location of the pi and the sensor, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps verify the operation of the PIR first.

Here is a cut-down version which works with my PIR on GPIO 4 (pin 7).

```py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as io

io.setmode(io.BCM)
pir_pin = 4

turned_off = False
io.setup(pir_pin, io.IN)

while True:
   if io.input(pir_pin):
      if turned_off:
         turned_off = False
         print("turned on")
   else:
      if not turned_off:
         turned_off = True
         print("turned off")
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! :)

I impemented your code, the result was when i remove the PIR plug from the pi i get "turned off" when i put it back on i get "turned on".

But nothing is printing when i just move infront of the sensor.

Comment: @JohanGurk You need to edit your question and include a photo of the Pi/PIR and connections.

Comment: Joan, I added a more specific question! Is the picture i have not enought to show the PI/PIR connection? Is a real photo recuired so I'll add one!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The scematics i followd were wrong. I switched places of the power and GND wire on the PIR and now it can detect motion!